How can I authenticate both an ASP.NET Web API and an ASP.NET MVC application using Azure Authentication with custom claims?
How can I authenticate both an ASP.NET Web API and an ASP.NET MVC application using Azure Authentication, and add custom claims that can be utilized in both the client and server for logic implementation?
I have an Azure app registration for an ASP.NET MVC application. When a user signs in to the ASP.NET MVC application, they receive an access token which is sent in the header to the API to get JSON data. This part is working correctly.
However, I want to add custom claims to the token so that when the user accesses the API, I can include an authentication role, such as SomeRole. Additionally, I want to decorate the ASP.NET MVC app with role-based authentication. How can I achieve this?
ASP.NET MVC code in Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
     .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
     {
         builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
         options.ClientSecret = "89898";
         options.SaveTokens = true;
         options.Events ??= new OpenIdConnectEvents();
         options.Events.OnTokenValidated += async context =>
         {
            // var someService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ISomeService>();
      //       var someValue = await someService.SomeMethod();
             context.Principal.AddIdentity(new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim> { new Claim("Foo", "Bar") }));
         };
     })
     .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[] { "api://123/.default" })
     .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

ASP.NET Web API code in Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidIssuer = $"https://sts.windows.net/{builder.Configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"]}/",
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidAudience = "api://123",
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)
    }
});


You can define roles on the azure side https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/howto-add-app-roles-in-apps

The problem is this that all roles in my database which I want to add through a logic depending user that day tasks. So want to add claims in the access token once’s so I can use it.

The trick to getting this working is to understand how .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp() and .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi() differ in how they use the "options pattern". The provided AuthenticationBuilder extension methods are different. But under the hood, the two authentication schemes are actually very similar and can be configured in the same way.
var authConfig = Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd");
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(authConfig);
services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<JwtBearerOptions>, ConfigureJwtOptions>();

public class ConfigureJwtOptions: IConfigureNamedOptions<JwtBearerOptions>{
    public void Configure(JwtBearerOptions options) { }
    public void Configure(string name, JwtBearerOptions options) {
        if (name == JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme) {
            options.Events.OnTokenValidated += async context => { 
                // configure web api token validation
            };
        }
    }
}

var authConfig = Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd");
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(authConfig);
services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<MicrosoftIdentityOptions>, ConfigureMSOptions>();

public class ConfigureMSOptions: IConfigureNamedOptions<MicrosoftIdentityOptions>{
    public void Configure(JwtBearerOptions options) { }
    public void Configure(string name, MicrosoftIdentityOptions options) {
        if (name == OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme) {
            options.Events.OnTokenValidated += async context => { 
                // configure web app token validation
            };
        }
    }
}

You can even combine the above into a single asp.net core application. Defining multiple authentication policies to split which end points can be accessed with each authentication scheme.
